# Switching between numeric and authoryear in Natbib

Tags: citing, natbib

I need to switch between numeric and authoryear style in Natbib, in the same document. Particularly, I want it to be numeric the first time a citation is used and authoryear any subsequent times. Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Particularly I find this somehow awkward since it will disrupt the consistency of the citations. That being said, one option would be to use the `numbers` package option for `natbib` and to use `\cite` the first time that a bibliographical reference will be cited and then a combination of `\citeauthor` and `\citeyear` for the subsequent citations of the same bibliographical item; something along these lines:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}

\newcommand\Mycite[1]{%
  \citeauthor{#1}~[\citeyear{#1}]}

\begin{document}

First citation: \cite{goossens93}
Second citation: \Mycite{goossens93}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{biblio}

\end{document}
```

with biblio.bib:

```
@book{goossens93,
    author = "Michel Goossens and Frank Mittlebach and Alexander Samarin",
    title = "The Latex Companion A",
    year = "1993",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    address = "Reading, Massachusetts"

}
```

resulting in:

[image]

Comment: Awesome suggestion! However, sadly this doesn't support the use of arguments e.g. `\citep[e.g. ][Chapter 1]{rasmussen05_gpml}`. Do you have any idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

You may use `[\citenum{author99}]` for number citation, and `\citet{author99}` for author-year style.

Look at https://gking.harvard.edu/files/natnotes2.pdf