# A custom authoryear citation in a numeric bibliography is not working

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, ieeetran

I am using `natbib` package with IEEE citation style. The citation is mainly numeric but I would also like to mention author, year, and reference number (because the style is actually numeric with only one bibliography). For this, I use the following command

```
\newcommand{\citeauyear}[1]{%
    \citeauthor{#1}~[\citeyear{#1}] [Ref. \citenum{#1}]}
```

Which is a modified version of the answer in [Switching between numeric and authoryear in Natbib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17058/switching-between-numeric-and-authoryear-in-natbib). The command above works well with plainnat bibliography style but provides unidentified author and year when used with IEEEtran

[image: E]

```
\begin{filecontents*}{sample.bib}
@article{aldaoudeyeh2016,
    title={{Photovoltaic-battery scheme to enhance PV array characteristics in partial shading conditions}},
    author={Aldaoudeyeh, Al-Motasem I},
    journal={IET Renewable Power Generation},
    volume={10},
    number={1},
    pages={108--115},
    year={2016},
    publisher={IET}
}
@ARTICLE{wu2017,
    title={{Assessing Impact of Renewable Energy Integration on System Strength Using Site-Dependent Short Circuit Ratio}},
    author={Wu, Di and Li, Gangan and Javadi, Milad and Malyscheff, Alexander M and Hong, Mingguo and Jiang, John Ning},
    journal={IEEE Transactions on Sustainable Energy},
    year={2017},
    publisher={IEEE}
}
@article{wu2019,
    title={A method to identify weak points of interconnection of renewable energy resources},
    author={Wu, Di and Aldaoudeyeh, Al Motasem and Javadi, Milad and Ma, Feng and Tan, Jin and Jiang, John N and others},
    journal={International Journal of Electrical Power \& Energy Systems},
    volume={110},
    pages={72--82},
    year={2019},
    publisher={Elsevier}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[]{book}

\usepackage[x11names, svgnames]{xcolor}


\usepackage[square, nonamebreak, sort&compress, comma, numbers]{natbib} % For IEEE

\newcommand{\citeauyear}[1]{%
    \citeauthor{#1}~[\citeyear{#1}] [Ref. \citenum{#1}]}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{citecolor=SlateBlue2, citebordercolor=SlateBlue2, 
    linkbordercolor=DodgerBlue3, linkcolor=DodgerBlue3, urlcolor=Blue1, colorlinks=true}


\begin{document}

\citeauyear{wu2017}, \cite{aldaoudeyeh2016,wu2019,wu2017}

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{sample}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to use `IEEEtranN` for bibliography style. This type is based on `plainnat` and is compatible with `natbib` commands.

The standard IEEE bibliography (i.e., `IEEEtran`)

[image]

The `IEEEtranN` bibliography style

[image]

The two bibliographies are exactly the same but `IEEEtranN` works with the custom author-year citation.