# Biblatex - Change multicites style

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, multiple-citations

This is my bibliograpy setup:

```
\documentclass[
  12pt,
  italian,
  singlespacing,
  parskip,
  nohyperref,
  headsepline,
]{MastersDoctoralThesis}

[...]

\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=ieee,natbib=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\begin{document}
  [...]
  
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

When I cite multiple articles, I would like something like: `[1-2]` but with all the possibile solutions/commands that I tried I have always this result `[1], [2]`.
I tried this commands:

- `\citep{}{}`
- `\cites{}{}`

I also try with this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/98619/115397) that suggest to use the package `cite` but at compile time I have this error:

> "message": "Package biblatex: Incompatible package 'cite'.\n"

**MastersDoctoralThesis** as available at this [link](https://www.latextemplates.com/template/masters-doctoral-thesis).

Comment: Possibly related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/416444/118739

Comment: @AndiW I don't found nothing helpful :(

Comment: Sorry - just seen you're using natbib that i am not familiar with. Any luck with a variant of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/485837/118739 ?

Comment: @AndiW Since I use `biblatex` I can't use `IEEETran` or `IEEEtranN`. Apart of this I cant fin nothing

Comment: Did you add this loading-time option `style=numeric-comp`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fully compressed citations only work if you give the keys in the same pair of curly braces. That means that `\autocite{<key_1>,<key_2>,...,<key_n>}` give the desired output, but `\autocites{<key_1>}{<key_2>}{<key_n>}` may not. This is due to the way these commands and compressed citations are implemented.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=ieee,natbib=true]{biblatex}


\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,worman,geer}
Lorem \autocites{sigfridsson}{worman}{geer}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem [1]–[3] Lorem [1, 2, 3]]

Loading `natbib` or in fact any other citation package will not help.

Comment: I try also with the keys in the same pair of curly braces but it does't work. For example, If I use `\autocites{sigfridsson}{worman}` in output I have `[1]worman`

Comment: @th3g3ntl3man That shouldn't be happening. Is that output you can reproduce with the example document I posted or only with your larger document? I tried my code with MDT and the main points still hold: `\autocites` (with s) cannot sort or compress across different sets of curly braces. `\autocite` will sort and compress as long as you are within the same set of curly braces.